# C# is there a a spying framework like mockito for .NET 3.5?

Tags: c#, .net, mocking, spy, spying

I used to have a very convenient spying framework in java called [Mockito](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mockito). It allows you to mock **some** of methods on existing objects and also could tell you if others were called (you'd create a spy wrapper for that). Is there anything like that for C# in .NET 3.x?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It sounds like you are describing "partial mocks".  Some (most?) mocking frameworks have support for that.  I know for sure [Moq](https://github.com/Moq/moq4/wiki/Quickstart) and [RhinoMocks](http://ayende.com/Wiki/Default.aspx?Page=Rhino+Mocks+Partial+Mocks) do.

Comment: Thank you! Unfortunately the one we use doesn't do this https://github.com/nsubstitute/NSubstitute/issues/41 but Moq look like a great alternative

Answer (score 3):

They are out there, but they cost money.

You could try [JustMock](http://www.telerik.com/products/mocking.aspx) or [TypeMock](https://www.typemock.com/)